how to glow light area like emission shader
Light Area has some advantages over Emission shader. For example, the Spread parameter and few other convenient settings. An obvious advantages, isn't it ? And other advantages are described here : Area Light vs. Emissive Polygon.
Question
How to make the Light Area :

Glow itself like Emission shader
Light direct in one side like in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Oij5Oo-B74


If by glow itself you mean make it visible, create a plane with emission that you parent to the area? As for light in one side, is it not already the case with area?



a plane with emission -----------------------------------
So I will get two light sources and I need to adjust both of them?



The right way:
Select the light object:
Properties > Object > Ray Visibility > Camera checkbox
Thanks to Google https://devtalk.blender.org/t/area-lights-still-not-visible-in-cycles/9430

Many thanks to the development team and community for implementing this feature!!! ❤️‍❤️‍❤️‍
Before it was like this:
Poor and outdated way:
How to make lamp visible to camera in cycles?
https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/pcalin/simple_solution_to_make_light_sources_visible/
More fine and realistic adjustments by passing light through various combinations of materials - this is the way of professionals, experts.
In this topic I considered replacing the trivial glow from the outdated approach through the emission shader. This approach has its limitations and disadvantages, which were later eliminated and implemented in light objects.
